# Unclear referee's message

Tags: peer-review

I receive a message from a referee, but I didn't understand what was required of me exactly. The message is:

> please check again the typeset text of these lines

What kind of error do they refer to?

Comment: Typesetting could refer to font, font size or even line spacing...

Comment: Are these lines somehow strange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is vague, but check the text the referee has highlighted. Chances are you can see something wrong. The word "typeset" here could indicate a typesetting error - for example, perhaps you forgot to include a reference that the text cites (this makes LaTeX go [??]). Or it could just mean there's a spelling error, an ambiguous sentence, etc.

Either way, the reviewer pointed out which lines they're referring to, which should help you solve the issue.